# Push element in observable Angular 9

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular9, subscribe

I have an observable, that observable is a array of objects (of a videos) stored in a local storage. 
I have "function" in service like this for pushing a new video into array:
*Video is a interface*

```
    videoList: BehaviorSubject<Video[]> = new BehaviorSubject(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('videos') || '[]'));

    setVideo(video: Video): Observable<Video> {
            return this.videoList.pipe(
              switchMap(videoList => {
                videoList.push(video);
                localStorage.setItem('videos', JSON.stringify(videoList));
                this.videoList.next(videoList);
                return of(video);
               })
            );
           }
```

In other component i call it to push a new object (video) like this:

```
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddVideoFormComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
      data.id = this.index++;
      this.videoService.setVideo(data);
      this.table.renderRows();
    });
  }
```

But this don't work and i know it is my mistake. 
Before observable i used classic constants and functions and work just fine, now i have trouble with observables. Someone told me that  i need to subscribe on a pipe somehow but i can't find anywhere how to do that. Observables are new to me and very confusing.

Comment: hey, did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to update the value of `videoList`, this is what you can do instead:

```
setVideo(video: Video) {
  const updatedValue = [
    ...this.videoList.value,
    video,
  ];
  this.videoList.next(updatedValue)
  localStorage.setItem('videos', JSON.stringify(updatedValue));
}
```

This simplifies the above `setVideo` method without the need for using `pipe()`.